# How to select my a tag inside div to change color on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

Can't figure out how to access my `a` inside a `div` so `i` can make it change color on `:hover`.

CODE:

```css
.menu a {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #18973c;
  font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px darkGray, 0 2px 3px lightGray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ff6633;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-3 menu">
      <a href=""> Begin Addition Quiz </a>
      <a href=""> Begin Subtraction Quiz </a>
      <a href=""> Begin Multiplication Quiz </a>
      <a href=""> Begin Division Quiz </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9">
      <h1> Get Ready To Succeed In Math! </h1>
      <p>Click any button on the left to begin a mathematics quiz in that subject. Once you are finished you will be given your score!
        <p>With this website, you will never fail another math test again!
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `.menu a:hover {}` doesn't allow me to access the buttons I created above.

Comment: try `.menu a:hover {
color: #ff6633;
}`

Comment: Your code work as expected .. on hover the anchor `a` change background color

Answer (score 0):

Change the text color on hover as below.

```css
.menu a {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #18973c;
  font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px darkGray, 0 2px 3px lightGray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ff6633;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-3 menu">
      <a href=""> Begin Addition Quiz </a>
      <a href=""> Begin Subtraction Quiz </a>
      <a href=""> Begin Multiplication Quiz </a>
      <a href=""> Begin Division Quiz </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9">
      <h1> Get Ready To Succeed In Math! </h1>
      <p>Click any button on the left to begin a mathematics quiz in that subject. Once you are finished you will be given your score!
        <p>With this website, you will never fail another math test again!
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason when i test your code snippet it works, But when i add the exact same code to "coda" it doesnt work. Any clue whats going on?

Comment: Either debug in dev tools to see if some other style rule is overriding it or .add !important to color:blue to increase the specificity for testing purposes. !important is not a best practice. Use it only for testing.